# show the location of items in small area on Android, not by google map

Tags: android, listview, dictionary, location

I hope to show a list of items on map for a small area, like in a room, so I can't use google map for this. But I still need some basic functions, showing current position, target positions, and the directions. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forgot to make a closure on this-- later I use some indoor positioning systems to solve this problem.